# Isn't there a better way to display mathematical equations as labels, in Manipulate[ ] etc.?

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting, syntax, formatting, labeling

I often want to output a mathematical equation in a text environment, and I find it very cumbersome and often the result is also not satisfactory.

This example out of the "Advanced Manipulate Functionality" help page illustrates this quite well:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}],
 {n, 1, 10, 1}, {m, 1, n, 1}]
```

With "cumbersome" I mean the way it is entered as `Row[{"(", Column[{n, m}, Center], ") = ", Binomial[n, m]}]`.

With "not satisfactory" I mean, that math content is often not formatted nicely. In this example the parentheses are too small.

Isn't there a better way to display mathematical equations?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[Row[{TraditionalForm @ Defer @ Binomial[##] &[n, m], " = ", Binomial[n, m]}], 
  {n, 1, 10, 1}, {m, 1, n, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a better way to display mathematical equations?

Nothing beats $\LaTeX$ (Sorry Wolfram :)

so that is what I would do, thanks to [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) package.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 If[m > n, m = n];
 MaTeX["{" <> ToString@n <> "\\choose" <> ToString@m <> "}=" <> 
   ToString@Binomial[n, m], Magnification -> 2]
 ,
 {{n, 5, "n"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 2, "m"}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n, m}]
```

You can extend this to much more complicated math

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 If[from > to, from = to];
 Module[{int, int0},
  int0 = NIntegrate[integrand, {x, from, to}];

  MaTeX["
    \\begin{aligned}
    \\int_{" <> ToString@N@from <> "}^{" <> ToString@N@to <> "} " <> 
    integrandTeX
    <> " &= \\left[" <> antiTeX <> "\\right]_{" <> ToString@N@from <> 
    "}^{" <> ToString@N@to <> "}\\\\"
    <> " &= " <> ToString@int0
    <> "\\end{aligned}"
   , Magnification -> 1.2]
  ]
 ,
 {{from, 0, "from"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{to, 5.3, "to"}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{antiTeX, ""}, None},
 {{integrandTeX, ""}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {from, to},
 Initialization :> (
   integrand = Cos[x]^2/Sqrt[Cos[x]^4 + Cos[x]^2 + 1];
   anti = Integrate[integrand, x];
   antiTeX = ToString@TeXForm@anti;
   integrandTeX = ToString@TeXForm@integrand
   )]
```